# I want to get the colums and rows in loop to perform in uipath studio

Tags: excel, linq, uipath, uipath-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9eE3.png)

in this excel sheet there are 470 colums and 67 rows here i want to filter the colums one by one and rows also

i want to use in uipath and ineed Linq query for do this i wany that the colums has seperate loop and rows also in seperate loop

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Filter datatable to keep only the columns, then do the same for the rows

Comment: its take huge time around 50+ minutes thats why

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).